# Get a Backbone View's Parent class from an instance

Tags: javascript, oop, backbone.js

I am implementing a system where I manage view switching in order to clear any events carried by that view before rendering another. However, I need to look up the view in an array using an instance of the view. How can I get the view class of a view instance?

eg:

```
var myView = new MyView;
return myView.parent(); // this should return MyView
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for the [`constructor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor) property:

> Returns a reference to the Object function that created the instance's prototype.

So if you do this:

```
var v = new View;
```

then `v.constructor` will be `View`. And if you do this:

```
var views = [
    Backbone.View.extend({}),
    Backbone.View.extend({}),
    Backbone.View.extend({})
];

var v = new views[1];
for(var i = 0; i < views.length; ++i)
    if(v.constructor === views[i])
        console.log(i)
```

You'll get `1` in the console. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/EgURK/

Answer (score -1):

The way I solve this is to pass in `this` as part of the constructor and set an "instance variable" inside of the view.

You'd then wire up a getter function with the name "parent" to return it a la your example code:

```
var myView = new MyView( this );
return myView.parent();
```